# How to use IdentityServer3 or 4 in Azure B2c as custom policy

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

**github a issue reference  : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/issues/21**

So far i have tried with post man i get JWT token as response back https://kamidp.azurewebsites.net/core/connect/token/

When i try with using  Azure ad B2c custom policy/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml 
i unable to make post call or get any JWT token as response back.
Error we are getting on reply url page is :**tenant does not contain the required cryptographic key**

Any idea if some one has done in community. thanks

```
<ClaimsProviders>
<ClaimsProvider>
    <Domain>ACSL</Domain>
    <DisplayName>Login using ACSL</DisplayName>
    <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="ContosoProfile">
            <DisplayName>ACSL Employee</DisplayName>
            <Description>Login with your ACSL account</Description>
            <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
            <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
            <Metadata>
                <Item Key="METADATA">https://kamidp.azurewebsites.net/core/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
                <Item Key="ProviderName">ACSL</Item>
                <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://kamidp.azurewebsites.net/core/connect/authorize</Item>
                <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://kamidp.azurewebsites.net/core/connect/token</Item>
                <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://kamidp.azurewebsites.net/core/connect/userinfo</Item>
                <Item Key="ClaimsEndpointAccessTokenName">id_token</Item>
                <Item Key="ClaimsEndpointFormatName">format</Item>
                <Item Key="ClaimsEndpointFormat">json</Item>
                <Item Key="scope">api1</Item>
                <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
                <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
                <Item Key="client_id">renukey</Item>
            </Metadata> 
            <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="AcslExt" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_AcslExt"/>
            </CryptographicKeys>                
            <OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid"/>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid"/>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="contosoAuthentication" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="AzureADContoso" />
            </OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
            </OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop"/>
        </TechnicalProfile>
    </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer is here

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/issues/21

chrispadgettlivecom commented 3 minutes ago
Excellent, @kamranbashir, can you please post the above question with the azure-ad-b2c tag to Stack Overflow so it can be answered and then discovered by others?